# How to make a query where some rows are counted multiple times?

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have a table like this

```
gems
----------
id, color
1 , green
2 , green
3 , blue
4 , red
5 , red
6 , red
7 , rainbow  <<<<< OMNI COLOR
8 , rainbow  <<<<< OMNI COLOR
```

And I'm trying to get results like this

```
color count,   each rainbow is added to each color
---------------
color , count
green , 4
blue , 3
red , 5
```

I've been trying various combinations of joins and group bys but i'm not sure how to approach this.  In this example each normal color should only be counted once, but each rainbow gem needs to be counted multiple times, and in the real problem there are an X amount of distinct 'colors'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT `color`, (count(*) + rb.`cnt`) AS `count`
FROM gems,
     (SELECT COUNT(*) AS `cnt` FROM gems WHERE color='rainbow') AS rb
GROUP BY `color`
HAVING `color`<>'rainbow'
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4003/2/0) is a fiddle to show the query working.

Comment: @eggyal In his shown example there is no entry for 'rainbow' as well.

Comment: @Sirko I took off my downvote :) I was trying to come up with a way of doing this without sub-queries, but so far failed.

Comment: I get the impression he wants something along the lines of count colours then add the number of rainbow to all colours.

Comment: @eggyal or just use a `HAVING` clause. Saw that one too, while setting up a sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 2):

You want to join your table with a subquery that counts the number of rainbows, then group the results:

```
SELECT   color,
         COUNT(*) + t.rainbows AS count
FROM     gems
  JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS rainbows FROM gems WHERE color = 'rainbow') AS t
WHERE    color <> 'rainbow'
GROUP BY color
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00f2b/1).

Comment: also these aren't my actual table and column names ;p